# Multi Monitor KVM Switch

Tags: kvm-switch

Here is my current setup,

2 VGA Monitors
Mouse & Keyboard
Speakers

I would like a KVM switch that would allow me to use both monitors as consoles and then connect computers to the KVM Switch so I can assign each computer to one monitor.  I haven't really been able to find a solution for this in my searching.

I don't need dual monitors on any of the computers.

Does there exist such a product or would I be better off getting two KVM switches?

Comment: You means, each computers connect to one monitor each, and using the KVM switch only for the keyboard and mouse ?

Comment: no the monitors would be connected to the KVM switch as well, however the KVM switch would allow you to toggle which monitor belongs to which computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several manufacturers have switches like this, but they're expensive since they're usually designed for connecting 4, 8, or 16 computers to 2 or 4 consoles.

Answer (score 1):

Are you are looking for a K_M switch? For switching just the keyboard and mouse and leaving the video set statistically 1:1.

If this is your goal, there is a software solution called [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/). Each monitor is physically connected to each tower. Its meant to be a software Keyboard and mouse switch.